# Snowflake Datawarehousing Getting the timestamp and use it in Insert stament

Tags: insert, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am Trying to get the current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz in a variable and trying use the variable in the insert statement for a timestamp datatype its giving error and when i debug the format was "Mon Dec 09 2019 04:24:50 GMT-0800 (PST)" this in the return statement of the procedure. When i am trying to insert into a timestamp column using that variable its giving error.how to resolve this.

Comment: Please include the statements that you are using and the actual error being displayed.

Comment: var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: "select current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz"} );
        while (rs.next())
       {
      var end_ts = rs.getColumnValue(1) ;
    }

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 244 unexpected 'Dec'. syntax error line 1 at position 280 unexpected 'Mon'. syntax error line 1 at position 284 unexpected 'Dec'. syntax error line 1 at position 320 unexpected 'current_timestamp'. syntax error line 1 at position 339 unexpected '::'. At Statement.execute, line 65 position 36

Comment: var my_sql_command = "INSERT INTO XXX(LOAD_END_TS) VALUES("+end_ts+");" ;               
       //return my_sql_command;
               var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
       var result_set1 = statement1.execute();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leveraging Snowflake's variables instead.  The issue you are seeing is because you are setting the current_timestamp() to a text string and then trying to insert it back in, but JS is changing the format.  Do something like:

```
SET var = current_timestamp();

INSERT INTO XXX(LOAD_END_TS) VALUES ($var);
```

This will work for the duration of the session.  The other thing you could try is to change your INSERT in JS to something like:

```
var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: "select current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz::varchar"} );
var my_sql_command = "INSERT INTO XXX(LOAD_END_TS) VALUES('"+end_ts+"'::timestamp_ntz);" ;
```

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 66 unexpected 'Dec'. At Statement.execute, line  same error for var my_sql_command = "INSERT INTO XXX(LOAD_END_TS) VALUES("+end_ts+"::timestamp_ntz);" ;

Comment: Edited above to include single-quotes around end_ts in the last line.

Comment: Try with the single-quotes.

Comment: how to get the timestamp in JS and then insert to table for table column of timestamp...

Comment: Invalid expression [CAST('Mon Dec 09 2019 05:29:54 GMT-0800 (PST)' AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))] in VALUES clause At Statement.execute, line 7 with single quotes

Comment: Since its JS Store procedure and i can't use the first option

Comment: I have also re-edited my answer to include a different way to get the timestamp on your original select.  This will return the timestamp in a SQL formatted string, which Snowflake will be able to cast back to timestamp in the second query.

Comment: That's not true.  You could execute both of the SQL statements that I showed in SQL through JS SP.

Comment: Second option worked...var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: "select current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz::varchar"} );
var my_sql_command = "INSERT INTO XXX(LOAD_END_TS) VALUES('"+end_ts+"'::timestamp_ntz);" ; Excellent Mike..typecast to varchar worked..